# Can't completely get rid of tap highlight color in Phonegap 3.0 app on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, css, cordova, android-webview

I have problems completely getting rid of the dreaded highlight when tapping on an element in a Phonegap 3.0 app on Android 4.1.2.

When tapping on some elements, I first get an orange (in this case) highlight under the tapped element, but then in quick succession the parent element (or another ancestor element, not sure which) *also* shows a highlight!

I know that tap highlight can be "disabled" by [setting a transparent color](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/essential-phonegap-css-webkit-tap-highlight-color.html):

```
* {
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* For some Androids */
}
```

This actually works for most clickable elements in my app, but on some elements the parent/ancestor element *still* gets a highlight! I have created a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RX6hM/1/)** which shows how it looks on the device I'm testing on (A Samsung Galaxy S3). Yeah, that's right. I'm using jsfiddle as an animation tool :-)

I have tried everything discussed in another thread: [Disable orange outline highlight on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210481/disable-orange-outline-highlight-on-focus).

Since the tap highlight actually disappears on all element tapped with the css rule above, I'm starting to suspect this secondary larger highlight is indicating something other than a tap. But I have tried to extend the css rule to also apply to `*:hover, *:active, *:focus` without success.

I have also tried to attack the problem outside of css and in the Android app itself. First [setLightTouchEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) in WebSettings seemed promising, but A) it didn't work and B) From API level 18 it is obsolete and has no effect.

I'm really at a loss here. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try go through the demo i gave in the link. It some how removes the color using e.preventDefault().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you require .

[web kit tap color](http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/alternative-to-webkit-tap-highlight-color-in-phonegap-apps/)

go through the video at the end . will let you know if it is right or not . :)

and here's the git hub project

[github](https://github.com/samcroft/Better-Cordova-button-tap-feedback)

Comment: Interesting. However, it's a solution for _customizing_ the look of the tapped element, and it looks like it relies on being able to hide the default look by setting `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` to transparent, which is exactly what I'm having problems with. It also uses Zepto.js, so I need to make sure it doesn't conflict with any other plugin in my project.

Comment: Try play with it :) Might get a success . I guess it will not have . try it if you have a jquery conflict the I found a SO link :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210588/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-and-zepto-library-at-the-same-time

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on another project at the moment, so I don't have time to play around with this right now. I'll accept this answer because it _did_ give me something new to try. Most of the other answers posted css already suggested in the link I posted in my question, which I had already tried.

Comment: Thak you happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get rid of those outlines and borders and  by adding the 'outline' property to your existing css:

```
* {
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* For some Androids */
   outline: 0;
```

}

Optionally, add !important to each line, since apparently phonegap juggles some default styles as well.

Answer (score 1):

in your case try this,

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

Setting the alpha value here to zero should make it "invisible".

also some more lines are there to make it work fine,

Please refer class `.link` in updated [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/RX6hM/2/)

```
.link {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style:none; 
    outline-style:none; 
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Other things remain same..

Also, in case of (specially iPhone) I have seen that you we return from event.

Same as `preventDefault` in `jQuery`, so in phoneGap also this may work, as it is also JS based framework.

```
<a class="link"
  href="javascript:void(0);"
  ontouchstart="return true;"></a>
```

I think this will do, please try and reply if not done..

Comment: Thanks for trying to solve this. I'm afraid I was a bit unclear to the purpose of the jsfiddle: that's not the code I'm having problems with. The **sole** purpose of that jsfiddle is to show in the "results" window what it looks like when I tap on a menu in my app. Basically ignore the html/css/javascript windows and just have a look at the results window. I thought of creating a gif-animation, but decided that creating a jsfiddle would be just as quick :-). Regarding your tips: Unfortunately none of them make any difference as far as the secondary highlight is concerned.

Comment: Since I only get this strange behaviour once the code is running inside a Phonegap app I haven't tried to create a test case reproducing the problem (potentially a lot of work). What I'm (naively) hoping for is for someone to see my question and go: "Oh, _that_ highlight. To get rid of it you need to add this thingamajig to the whatchamacallit."

Answer (score 1):

CSS side:

```
  * {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
div {
-webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

I've found that on the user side, going into **Settings->Accessibility->Install web scripts** and changing that to 'Not Allowed' stops showing a highlight around hyperlinks. 
[(see screenshot)](https://db.tt/sPsheveq)

Unfortunately, I have no access to phonegap so I can't reproduce your actual situation.

Comment: Interesting regarding the "Install web scripts" setting. Unfortunately it's already set to the default "Not Allowed" on my device. About the css: I really can't see how setting alpha to 255 can make the highlight disappear? The alpha component should be between 0-1, where 1 is totally opaque, so setting it to 255 should be equal to setting it to 1.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't totally proof read this. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try,

```
* {
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
   -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```

This should remove the tapping highlight color for you case.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in a post that might also be super interesting, since you can edit your CSS for you needs:

**HTML**

```
<a class="html5logo"
  href="javascript:void(0);"
  ontouchstart="return true;"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.html5logo {
 display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url(/img/html5-badge-128.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* For some Androids */
}
.html5logo:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 1);
}
```

http://phonegap-tips.com/demos/webkit-tap-highlight-color.html

Or if you want to be fancy:
https://material.google.com/motion/choreography.html#choreography-creation